# How to remove consecutively repeated strings only if this strings are in the middle of "((VERB)" and ")"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-group

```
import re

input_text = "((VERB) saltar a nosotros a nosotros) a nosotros a nosotros a nosotros ((VERB)correr a nosotros) sdsdsd ((VERB) saltar a nosotros a nosotros)"

input_text = re.sub(r"\(\(VERB\)" + r"((?:\w\s*)+)" + r"\)", 
                    lambda x: re.sub(r"(a nosotros)\s*\1+", r"\1", x.group()), 
                    input_text)

print(input_text) # --> output
```

In this code I was trying to remove consecutively repeated `"a nosotros"` strings only if this strings are in the middle of `"((VERB)"` and `)"`, that is, that string that captures the capturing group `r"\(\(VERB\)" + r"((?:\w\s*)+)" + r"\)"`

This is the output you should be getting when running this script:

```
"((VERB) saltar a nosotros) a nosotros a nosotros a nosotros ((VERB)correr a nosotros) sdsdsd ((VERB) saltar a nosotros)"
```

Although the code that I have placed in the question does edit the input string, what should i modify?

Comment: Your regex expects a `)` after `(VERB`, but your string contains `((VERB saltar a nosotros a nosotros)` at the start, with no `)` after `VERB`. Is it a typo, or does it mean `)` is optional there?

Comment: If `)` is optional, you may just use  a code like https://ideone.com/tsuUG3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, it is not optional, I have edited the question there. The closing parenthesis is mandatory, even so the program does not work since it does not know the correct output

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks I tried with your pattern and it worked, by removing the character `?` which makes the previous optional `input_text = re.sub(r"\(\(VERB\)[\w\s]*\)",  lambda x: re.sub(r"\ba nosotros(?:\s+a nosotros)*\b", "a nosotros", x.group()), input_text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
input_text = re.sub(r"\(\(VERB\)[\w\s]*\)",  lambda x: re.sub(r"\ba nosotros(?:\s+a nosotros)*\b", "a nosotros", x.group()), input_text)
```

The main pattern is `\(\(VERB\)[\w\s]*\)`, it matches `((VERB)` + zero or more word or whitespace chars and then a `)` char.

The `re.sub(r"\ba nosotros(?:\s+a nosotros)*\b", "a nosotros", x.group())` part removes all consecutive whole words `a nosotros` inside the match.

Answer (score 1):

Python's optional regex engine module (developed by Matthew Barnett) supports the `\K` directive, which resets the starting point of the reported match to the current string pointer locations and discards any previously consumed characters from the final match. By employing that directive one can simply replace matches in the string with empty strings.

The code for doing that is as follows.

```
import regex

rgx = r"\(\(VERB\)(?:(?!\ba nosotros\b|\)).)*\K\ba nosotros\b(?=[^)]*\ba nosotros\b)"

txt_in = "((VERB) saltar a nosotros a nosotros) a nosotros a nosotros a nosotros ((VERB)correr a nosotros) sdsdsd ((VERB) saltar a nosotros a nosotros)"

txt_out = regex.sub(rgx, '', txt_in)

print(txt_out)
-> ((VERB) saltar  a nosotros) a nosotros a nosotros a nosotros ((VERB)correr a nosotros) sdsdsd ((VERB) saltar  a nosotros)
```

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
\(\(VERB\)          # match literal
(?:                 # begin non-capture group
  (?!               # begin negative lookahead
    \ba nosotros\b  # match literal surrounded by word boundaries
    |               # or 
    \)              # match literal 
  )                 # end of negative lookahead
  .                 # match any character other than a line terminator
)*                  # end non-capture group and execute zero or more times
\K                  # see the first paragraph of this answer
\ba nosotros\b      # match literal surrounded by word boundaries
(?=                 # begin positive lookahead
  [^)]*             # match any characters other than ')' zero or more times
  \ba nosotros\b    # match literal surrounded by word boundaries
)                   # end positive lookahead
```

[Python demo](https://replit.com/join/hjtwxrvbom-caryswoveland)<sup><sub><-</sub></sup><sub>\(ツ)/</sub><sup><sub>-></sub></sup>[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YSL1km/1)

The technique of matching one character at a time with a negative lookahead (here `(?:(?!\ba nosotros\b|\)).)`) is called the [tempered greedy token solution](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).